# Importing uuid in rollup ESM library creates an import statement for "crypto" in output file

Tags: dependencies, uuid, guid, cryptojs, rollup

Edit: Added plugins configuration for more clarity

---

I am using `uuid` package in a rollup project. At first I was getting a warning for external dependency **crypto**. So I added `external` and `output.globals` in my rollup configuration:

```js
export default [{
  input: '/path/to/input.js',
  external: ['crypto'],
  output: {
    file: '/path/to/output.esm.js',
    format: 'esm',
    ...
    globals: {
      crypto: 'crypto'
    }
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
      customResolveOptions: {
        moduleDirectory: 'node_modules'
      },
      preferBuiltins: true
    }),
    commonjs({
      namedExports: {
        uuid: ['v4']
      }
    })
  ]
}];
```

The warning is gone, but now I have an import statement in my output file:

output.esm.js

```js
import crypto from 'crypto';
...
```

My question is will this work if I include `output.esm.js` in browser?

```html
<script type="module" src="/path/to/output.esm.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you using `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`? If yes, can you show its config?

Comment: @Umbo I have updated my question to include plugin-node-resolve configuration

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> At first I was getting a warning for external dependency crypto

This is because Rollup doesn't know whether you want to use node's built-in `crypto` or an external package. `@rollup/plugin-node-resolve`'s `preferBuiltins` is used to choose between one of these alternatives.

> So I added external and output.globals in my rollup configuration

These options, together with `preferBuiltins: true` tell Rollup to use node's built-in `crypto` without bundling it (hence the import statement still present in the output file).

However if your target environment is the browser, you should use the [browser alternative](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/blob/master/package.json#L21) provided by `uuid` that relies on the Web Crypto API instead of node's `crypto`. To do this, the following Rollup config should be enough:

```js
// rollup.config.js

export default [{
  input: ...,
  output: {
    file: ...,
    format: 'esm',
  },
  plugins: [
    resolve({
        browser: true, // This instructs the plugin to use
                       // the "browser" property in package.json
    }),
    commonjs(),
  ],
}];
```

---

Just out of curiosity:

> My question is will this work if I include output.esm.js in browser?
>
> `<script type="module" src="/path/to/output.esm.js"></script>`

No, it won't; mainly because browsers don't understand bare module specifiers (`import crypto from 'crypto'` instead of `'./path/to/crypto.js'`). Also, as per your Rollup configuration `crypto` is treated as a nodejs built-in, which is not available in the browser unless bundled :)

Comment: Just one more question. Crypto module is vastly different from its browser counter part. I was looking at the source code of uuid and found a dependency on a method called ``getRandomBytes`` which is available in node API but missing in browser. Does this ensure that those are polyfilled? Or I am understanding it all wrong and the option ``browser: true`` will bundle node's crypto library as part of the output.

Comment: You got it right, it won't be bundled. Well, in principle - unless you want to directly use crypto - you shouldn't worry about polyfills: `uuid`'s readme would mention that. Also, I would say [this](https://github.com/uuidjs/uuid/search?q=getRandomBytes&unscoped_q=getRandomBytes) is a pretty good sign that `getRandomBytes ` won't be called anywhere.

Comment: Confirming that for use of uuid in the browser, nodeResolve({ browser: true }) works. For the sake of searchability, the errors that occur without "browser: true" are: 1) In Rollup: "(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
crypto (imported by node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-node/rng.js, node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-node/md5.js, node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-node/sha1.js)" and 2) In Chrome: "Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "crypto". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../"."

Comment: none of these options fix the issue for me. I've been trying several different layout libraries for react. Every one of them seems use crypto, probably for uuids, I get error mentioned in the question. `browser:true` was already in my nodeResolve, adding `preferBuiltins: true` didn't fix it. Any other ideas?  [My rollup.config.js](https://pastebin.com/8ZtxkDiE)