# How to get rollup to deal with node based libraries in the browser

Tags: javascript, node.js, rollupjs

I've been trying to use some react layout libraries. Most of them seem to rely on making random ids using uuid or crypto.

When I try to run the result of building with them I get this error in the browser

> `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "crypto". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".`

I've seen various possible solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59937658/importing-uuid-in-rollup-esm-library-creates-an-import-statement-for-crypto-in) and [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node)
but they're not solving the issue for me so I must have a different problem that needs a different solution.

I've spent about 16hrs trying various things. I even just gave up for a week and made do with libraries that didn't have these dependencies. But, I finally ran into a need to use a library that has this issue and I'm back to spending hours trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong.

[Here's a repo](https://github.com/greggman/rollup-module-issue/archive/refs/heads/main.zip)

I know it looks a little large but it is an MCVE. Further, I just wanted to make sure the question is about this specific example so that any solutions fit.

If you [get](https://github.com/greggman/rollup-module-issue/archive/refs/heads/main.zip)/make those files and then

```
npm install
npm start
```

If it works there should be no errors in the JS console but I removed the CSS so it will likely not show anything. For me though it gets the error mentioned above.

I can't be the only person running into this issue though. I see [people asking and not getting answers as well as comments seeking solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64644241/i-cant-get-rollup-to-compile-properly-when-using-dynamic-imports-and-crypto-js-i).

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "delme-rollup",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "type": "module",
  "module": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "rollup -c rollup.config.js -w"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "^23.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-replace": "^5.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^9.0.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.8",
    "postcss": "^8.4.18",
    "rollup": "^3.2.3",
    "rollup-plugin-dts": "^5.0.0",
    "rollup-plugin-livereload": "^2.0.5",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "^4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-serve": "^2.0.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "flexlayout-react": "^0.7.5"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

`rollup.config.js`

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import fs from 'fs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import livereload from 'rollup-plugin-livereload';
import serve from 'rollup-plugin-serve';

const packageJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('package.json', 'utf8'));

export default [
    {
        input: 'src/index.tsx',
        output: [
            {
                file: packageJson.module,
                format: 'esm',
                sourcemap: true,
            },
        ],
        // This is a hack to workaround a warning that should be fixed
        onwarn(warning, warn) {
            if (warning.code === 'THIS_IS_UNDEFINED') {
                return;
            }
            warn(warning);
        },
        plugins: [
            resolve({
                preferBuiltins: true,
                browser: true,
            }),
            replace({
                preventAssignment: true,
                values: {
                    'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
                },
            }),
            commonjs({
                include: /node_modules/,
                requireReturnsDefault: 'auto', // <---- this solves default issue
            }),
            typescript({ tsconfig: './tsconfig.json', sourceRoot: '/src/ui' }),
            postcss({
                minimize: true,
                sourceMap: true,
                extract: 'styles.css',
            }),
            serve({
                open: true,
                openPage: '/',
                verbose: true,
                contentBase: [''],
                host: 'localhost',
                port: 3000,
            }),
            livereload({ watch: 'dist' }),
        ],
    },
];
```

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "jsx": "react",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "noErrorTruncation": true,
    "declarationDir": "types",
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*stories",
    "**/*types"
  ]
}
```

`index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="container"></div>
    <script type="module" src="dist/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`src/index.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import * as FlexLayout from 'flexlayout-react';
//import 'light.css';

const json = {
    global: {},
    layout: {
        type: 'row',
        weight: 100,
        children: [
            {
                type: 'tabset',
                weight: 50,
                selected: 0,
                children: [
                    {
                        type: 'tab',
                        name: 'One',
                        component: 'panel',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { model: FlexLayout.Model.fromJson(json) };
    }

    factory = node => {
        const component = node.getComponent();
        if (component === 'panel') {
            return <div className="tab_content">{node.getName()}</div>;
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="spector2">
                <div className="spector2-debugger">
                    <FlexLayout.Layout model={this.state.model} factory={this.factory} />;
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const elem = document.createElement('div');
document.body.appendChild(elem);
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(elem);
root.render(<App />);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first solve problems in your terminal. Which are like compile errors. Then ones in a browser, which are more like runtime.

For example for me terminal displays:

[image]

Also created [PR](https://github.com/greggman/rollup-module-issue/pull/1). Which solves type issues, but still has implementation errors.

Comment: All it needed was `@types/uuid`. Thanks! Yes of course the errors would be fixed but they were irrelevant to the issue. As for the implemention, that's a matter of re-enabling the css. Thanks a ton. It's suprising to me this "add the types" is not some how automated so a project's package.json can't just refer to the types it exposes internally.